# what does this do in matlab. [M , p] = max(a3 , [] , 2);

Tags: matlab

what does the left side of the following command do in matlab.

[M , p] = max(a3 , [] , 2);

a3 is a matrix.

Comment: Find it described here in the documentation https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It searches for the max value in the array `a3` along the second dimension.
The variable `M` will have the max value and the variable `p` will have the index of the value (Column Index).

For instance:

```
>> mA = reshape(randperm(9), [3, 3])

mA =

     7     5     4
     2     6     1
     8     9     3

>> [vA, vB] = max(mA, [], 2)

vA =

     7
     6
     9


vB =

     1
     2
     2
```

So the variable `vA`has the maximum value along row and `vB` has the column index.
For the first row, the max value is 7 on column 1.
For the first row, the max value is 6 on column 2.
For the first row, the max value is 9 on column 2.